# Prove cycling in a Rubik's cube

Tags: algorithms, rubiks-cube, theorem-provers

How can I prove that if you apply some algorithm over and over again on a solved Rubik's cube, the cube will be solved?

I mean mathematically not conceptually.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Lol, I mean when you starts in a solved position

Comment: Permutations have a finite order in a group. Say, $S_{54}$ for the 54 stickers, though a smaller group will suffice. The claim follows from this immediately. Mind you, I disprove of the parlance `an algorithm = a sequence of moves`. I know it's commonplace among cubers, but to me an algorithm has branches, loops and stuff :-)

Comment: I would interprete this question as follows : Is there a sequence of moves that , if repeated over and over again , will solve the cube after some number of applications , no matter of the initial configuration ? That a SOLVED cube will eventually be solved again is trivial because the permutation corresponding to the sequence of moves contains finite many cycles with finite length, the lcm of the lengths is the number of applications we need.

Comment: @Peter But that variant of the question is also trivially answered in the negative. That sequence of moves generates a cyclic group. In particular that group is abelian, but the group of permutations on a cube is not.

Comment: This is obvious but I want a mathematical prove...

Comment: Of course, you may consider the variant where you don't necessarily repeat the entire sequence, and allow the situation where the cube is in a solved state, say, after $22$ full and $37/1260$ partial runs of a sequence. That variant, in turn, is trivially true, because we can hyperlong sequence cycling through all the possible states.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I do not quite understand , how we can show that , given a sequence of moves , we can find a SOLVABLE starting configuration that is not solved by repeating the sequence over and over again. Can you explain the point with the non-abelian group a bit further ?

Comment: Call the permutation that the sequence of move corresponds to $g$. By repeating that sequence you get permutations $g, g^2,g^3,\ldots$. All those permutations commute with each other because $g^i\cdot g^j=g^{i+j}=g^{j+i}=g^j\cdot g^i$. But the group of all possible permutations corresponding to all solvable states is not abelian. Therefore there exists a permutation $h$ that comes from a legal sequence of moves, but is not a power of $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of "moves" on a rubix cube forms a group, and since there are only finitely many states a rubix cube can be in, this group is finite. It is an early theorem of group theory that every element of a finite group has finite order. That is, repeating a move of a finite group will always bring you back where you started in a finite number of repetitions.

If you want me to prove any of these claims, or elaborate more on why the rubix cube moves form a group, etc. Let me know, and I'll elaborate when I'm at a desktop instead of on mobile. I'm not sure what your background with group theory is, so I'm not sure what you need me to include.

---

**Edit:**

Ok, I'm back. Let's go a bit more in depth on how everything I just mentioned works.

First - What does the rubix cube have to do with a group?

Second - Why does any element of a finite group have finite order, and what does this mean?

Third - Why does this let us conclude that, if we start from a solved cube, repeating any sequence of moves will always (eventually) get us back to a solved state.

---

Let's look at the set of all sequences of moves, or "algorithms" as the cubers call them. I claim these form a group, where group multiplication is "do the first algorithm, then do the second algorithm".

Notice there is an identity algorithm, where we just... don't move anything.

There is also an inverse algorithm for any algorithm. We reverse the order and direction of each "primitive" move. So ULR' --> RL'U'. It is easy to see that this will always give an inverse (or you could induct on the length of the algorithm, if you want).

Finally, algorithm-composition is associative. Doing algorithm AB then C is the same sequence of moves as doing algorithm A then BC, because we do the same moves in the same order no matter what.

Ok, so we have a group. But there's infinitely many algorithms I could try! After all, L, LL, LLL, LLLL, LLLLL, ... and so on are all different algorithms.
Of course, we know that LLLL is the same thing as the identity algorithm.

Let's see how to make this more general. Let's identify an algorithm A with the state it brings the rubix cube to when we start solved. So the identity algorithm, LLLL, UUUU, and so on all correspond to a solved cube. Whereas L corresponds to a solved cube, but with, say, the orange face rotated once (here I'm holding the cube with white on bottom, orange on left).

Now, there are only a finite number of states the rubix cube can be in, so many of our algorithms will correspond to the same state. If we consider two algorithms "equivalent" if they send the solved cube, we will get a quotient group with only finitely many elements -- one for each state the cube can be in.

It is possible that this is too complicated, so I'll give a simple example of the same principle. Let's say we have a button which turns a light on and off. There is only one "move" here, P, for "push the button". We again have a bunch of "algorithms" we can build out of this, but each one looks like $P^n$ for some number of presses. These algorithms again form a group (albeit a much simpler one). We again consider two algorithms "equivalent" if they leave the light in the same position. So P, PPP, PPPPP, and so on are all equivalent, because they turn the light on. Similarly, PP, PPPP, PPPPPP, and so on (plus the identity algorithm) are equivalent because they leave the light off.

Now we can quotient our group by this equivalence, and we are left with a group with 2 elements: $\{P, PPP, PPPPP, \ldots\}$ and $\{\langle \rangle, PP, PPPP, PPPPPP,\ldots\}$. Here we have one group element for each reachable state. We are doing the same thing with our rubix cube, it is just a more complicated object (Also, I wrote $\langle \rangle$ for the "do nothing" algorithm, because it's hard to show it otherwise).

---

Ok, so now we know that we have one group element for each reachable state. Let's show a group theory fact that will help us:

Theorem: If $G$ is a finite group, and $g \in G$, then $g^n = 1$ for some $n$.

Proof:
Consider $\{g^0, g^1, g^2, g^3,\ldots\}$. This set is infinite, but $G$ is finite. So there must be some $g^i = g^j$ by the pigeonhole principle. Without loss of generality, say $i < j$. Then by multiplying both sides by $g^{-i}$, we see $g^i = g^j$ becomes $1 = g^0 = g^{j-i}$. So repeating $g$ some number of times (in particular $j-i$ times) is the same thing as doing nothing.

---

Finally we see the light at the end of the tunnel! We know that the set of all algorithms (where we identify two algorithms that "do the same thing") is a finite group! So by the above theorem, we are guaranteed that any algorithm $A$ has $A^n = 1$ for some $n$. Now we are done! Because $A^n = 1$ means $A^n$ does the same thing as the do nothing algorithm, so $A^n$ doesn't change the cube.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I have learned group theory but in your prove you just use the finite size of the group. In the same way I can say that if you apply $R$ than you apply $U$ over and over again you will solve the cube because there are finitely many states. If you mean that this changes the places of the elements in the group this make sense but then you need to prove that if you apply a permutation for finite many time (bigger than zero) on a finite group the group will get back the way it was, and I have never seen such a prove. I will be happy if there is one (this is actually very obvious).

Comment: (Thank you anyway)

Comment: I can prove that for you as soon as I'm home. If someone beats me to it, they can edit my answer to include it too!

Comment: About the group theorem I can't see why it is true for example let $G$ to be {0} then for any natural number g to the n won't be 1.

Comment: By $1$, I mean the identity of the group. If your group is $\{0\}$, then the identity is $0$, and $0^1$ works. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, this is a theorem of group theory, but it’s easy enough to give the argument without explicitly mentioning groups. First, observe that any sequence of moves can be undone by doing them backwards and returning to the same position. Now observe if you repeat the same algorithm over and over again, and at any point you return to a configuration you’ve seen before, then you must have returned to your initial configuration before that. (Say you see a certain configuration after 100 iterations and again after 500 iterations. Then you must have seen the initial configuration after 400 iterations since we know we can rewind by 100 and reach the initial configuration.) Finally, observe that there are only finitely many configurations, so by the pigeonhole principle you must eventually see one twice.

Comment: That's a really slick approach! Great addition ^_^ sometimes it's hard to remember simpler approaches

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks, but I don't think it's any simpler... it's the same usual proof of Lagrange's theorem, just avoiding abstraction.